# Trying to solve an equation with unknown matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am stuck in a simple problem. Assume we have two vectors which are known for example

```
v1 = (5 , 6 ,7) and v2 =(10,-40,30
```

and we want to find an unknown matrix A so that

```
v2 = A*v1
```

I tried

```
A = sym('A', [3 3])
equation = A *v1' - v2 == 0;

Solution = solve(equation)
```

however I get the following outcome

```
Solution = 

 struct with fields:

   A1_1: [0×1 sym]
   A1_2: [0×1 sym]
   A1_3: [0×1 sym]
   A2_1: [0×1 sym]
   A2_2: [0×1 sym]
   A2_3: [0×1 sym]
   A3_1: [0×1 sym]
   A3_2: [0×1 sym]
   A3_3: [0×1 sym]
```

where every value is Empty sym: 0-by-1
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I also made `v1` and `v2` column vectors and did the matrix division, but the values I get for `A` are different than what ThomasIsCoding got.

```
v1 = [5 , 6 ,7]';
v2 = [10, -40, 30]';
A = v2/v1

A =

         0         0    1.4286
         0         0   -5.7143
         0         0    4.2857
```

When you check if A*v1 = v2, it does, so my solution is correct

```
>> A*v1

ans =

    10
   -40
    30
```

I think this problem may have multiple solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a transpose. Try this:

```
equation = A *v1' - v2' == 0
Solution = solve(equation, A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the matrix division like below

```
>> v2'/v1'
ans =

   0.4545   0.5455   0.6364
  -1.8182  -2.1818  -2.5455
   1.3636   1.6364   1.9091
```

such that

```
>> ans*v1'-v2'
ans =

   3.5527e-15
  -1.4211e-14
   1.4211e-14
```